# Issue with Python Package Upload to PyPI - Invalid Directory Structure

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging

I am encountering an issue while uploading my Python package to PyPI. I have followed the standard steps for creating a distribution package using python setup.py sdist and python setup.py bdist_wheel, but the resulting package on PyPI has an unexpected directory structure.

I have a Python project with the following structure:

```
my_project/
|-- setup.py
|-- my_module/
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- ...
```

After running python setup.py sdist and python setup.py bdist_wheel, the dist directory contains both a .tar.gz file and a .whl file.

Upon uploading to PyPI using twine upload dist/*, the package is successfully uploaded, but when users download and install it, they find an unexpected directory structure in their site-packages:

```
site-packages/
|-- my_project-1.0.0.dist-info/
    |-- ...
```

What should i do?

Edit:

```
my_project/
|-- setup.py
|-- my_module/
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- screen.py
    |-- test.txt
    |-- my_module/
        |-- dependency_links.txt
        |-- PKG-INFO
        |-- requires.txt
        |-- SOURCES.txt
        |-- top_level.txt
|-- dist/
    |-- my_module-1.1.5-py3-none-any.whl
    |-- my_module-1.1.5.tar.gz
|-- build/
    |-- bdist.win-amd64
    |-- lib/
        |-- __init__.py
        |-- screen.py
```

```
site-packages/
|-- my_project-1.0.0.dist-info/
    |-- INSTALLER
    |-- METADATA
    |-- RECORD
    |-- REQUESTED
    |-- top_level.txt
    |-- WHEEL
```

Comment: There's nothing you can do about it - it's part of the process of the installation - https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/recording-installed-packages/

Comment: @AnyaShenanigans There are none of my scripts inside of my project. Is this normal?

Comment: I'm not understanding the comment - are you saying that the folder structure isn't in your project and you're wondering where it comes from, or are you missing the various .py package files from your package?

Comment: Your code is installed under the `my_module` directory not in `my_project`. Former is import package, latter is distribution package. See glossary: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/glossary/

Comment: I recommend looking at the content of the distribution archive (sdist and wheel) before uploading

Comment: This last edit you made does not bring much useful information. -- I recommend you rewrite the question to show the content of `setup.py` (no need to write an "edit" paragraph at the end, we can look at the history ourselves). -- I also recommend you study this tutorial thoroughly: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to include this in my `setup.py` file:

```
    package_data={
        'my_module': ['__init__.py', 'screen.py'],
    },
```

Comment: That seems like a very incorrect way to go about it.